# How to use module after it's installed via npm/yarn?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, module, yarnpkg

I know that is a simple question, however I really struggle with it. 
My problem is that I have no idea what to do after I installed a bootstrap module via yarn in my react app

I have it in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
     ...
```

But how to use it in my app? I don't have style links pointing to it, I've also tried just adding bootstrap classes in my index.html, but nothing changed

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: @mersocarlin I do use create-react-app

Comment: So it's easy! https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap